# Devise no destroy_user_session route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes

`destroy_user_session` doesn't appear in my routes although `routes.rb` is configured

```
# routes.rb #
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
root :to => 'home#home'
```

and rake gives

```
$ rake routes

user_omniauth_callback        /users/auth/:action/callback(.:format) {:action=>/facebook/, :controller=>"users/omniauth_callbacks"}
                  root        /                                      {:controller=>"home", :action=>"home"}
                events GET    /events(.:format)                      {:action=>"index", :controller=>"events"}
                       POST   /events(.:format)                      {:action=>"create", :controller=>"events"}
             new_event GET    /events/new(.:format)                  {:action=>"new", :controller=>"events"}
            edit_event GET    /events/:id/edit(.:format)             {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"events"}
                 event GET    /events/:id(.:format)                  {:action=>"show", :controller=>"events"}
                       PUT    /events/:id(.:format)                  {:action=>"update", :controller=>"events"}
                       DELETE /events/:id(.:format)                  {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"events"}
                 users GET    /users(.:format)                       {:action=>"index", :controller=>"users"}
                       POST   /users(.:format)                       {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users"}
              new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                   {:action=>"new", :controller=>"users"}
             edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)              {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"}
                  user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                   {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
                       PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                   {:action=>"update", :controller=>"users"}
                       DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                   {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"users"}
                 posts GET    /posts(.:format)                       {:action=>"index", :controller=>"posts"}
                       POST   /posts(.:format)                       {:action=>"create", :controller=>"posts"}
              new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)                   {:action=>"new", :controller=>"posts"}
             edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)              {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"posts"}
                  post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                   {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts"}
                       PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)                   {:action=>"update", :controller=>"posts"}
                       DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)                   {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"posts"}
```

How can this even be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer just at the end of typing, but I posted it anyway because it might help some people.

In my `user.rb` model, I had

```
devise :omniauthable
```

But Devise needs the module `:database_authenticatable` in order to have these routes. Mystery solved!